# How to access Business Central data through api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo, dynamics-business-central

I have made a page in Business Central, and i'm trying to access that page in an expo app.

I got authorization working, but I'm having troubles trying to access the page.

UPDATE

Here's what's up:

```
const getTimesheets = async () => {
    const timeSheetEndpoint = `https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/${tenantId}/Sandbox/ODataV4/Company(${companyId})/${endpointName}`;
    var token = await fetch(
        `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token`,
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            body:
                "grant_type=client_credentials" +
                "&scope=https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default" +
                "&client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret,
        }
    )
        .then((result) => {
            const token = result.json();
            console.log(token);
            return token;
        })

    var json = await fetch(timeSheetEndpoint, {
        method: "Get",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            const { value } = json;
            if (value == undefined || value == null) {
                return json;
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        })
        .catch((e) => alert("Error fetching user data", e));

    console.log(json);
    return json;
}
```

Here i get an unhandled promise rejection in the terminal.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
> at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:null in setTimeout$argument_0
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _allocateCallback$argument_0
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in callTimers
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __callFunction
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard$argument_0
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Have any of you tried something similar? How did you do it?
I have tried using Postman, and it works, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it in js.

Comment: did the URL call in your app? what is its response?

Comment: Does it work like this in Postman? The URL looks wrong. It should be "/Sandbox/companies('${companyId}')/${endpointName}". {endpointName} is the name of the service in the BC Web Services page.

Comment: Well, it might look wrong, but i put the {endpointName} together with the {companyId}, so the url is basically the same as the one you say it should be like.

Comment: did you get any logs in your console?

Comment: Yes, the token 'appears' as it should.

Comment: i mean logs in `then` and `catch`

Comment: Can you add the code of the page you created?

Comment: @kaspermoerch the created page is basically a copy of page 950 "Time Sheet"

Comment: @AliHosseini ofcourse, sorry, no i don't get any logs there. I get a `JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer on 2023-03-03**

I think the unhandled promise rejection is could be caused by the `then` part of your token request.

Calling `result.json()` returns a `promise`, not the actual `JSON Object`.

In order to handle that `promise` you need an extra `then`:

```
var token = await fetch(
    `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token`,
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: body
    }
)
.then((result) => result.json())
.then((token) => {
    console.log(token);
    return token;
})
```

**Updated answer on 2023-03-02**

First of all you have a rouge commas after `ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, `clientSecret`, `Authorization: "Bearer " + token` and also after the `headers` object, which might make the object invalid.

Another possible cause of the error is that the body of your token request is not url encoded.

This can be done like this:

```
var body = [];
body.push(encodeURIComponent('grant_type') + "=" + encodeURIComponent('client_credentials'));
body.push(encodeURIComponent('scope') + "=" + encodeURIComponent('https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default'));
body.push(encodeURIComponent('client_id') + "=" + encodeURIComponent(clientId));
body.push(encodeURIComponent('client_secret') + "=" + encodeURIComponent(clientSecret));
body = body.join("&");
```

And then you use the `body` variable within your `fetch`:

```
var token = await fetch(
    `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token`,
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: body
    }
)
```

---

**Answer from 2023-03-01**

There are a few things that could be the cause, so you need to check each of them to see which one could solve your problem.

**Web Services**

In order for the page to be visible as an ODataV4 endpoint it needs to be created as a `Web Service` through the Business Central client. When you create the `Web Service` you give it a `Service Name` which will be a part of the URL.

Make sure that the Web Service is marked as **Published** after creating it.

**URL**

Assuming you named your Web Service `timeSheet` then the final URL would look like this:

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{tenantId}/{environmentName}/ODataV4/Company('{companyName}')/timeSheet
```

Note that the Company Name must be **URL encoded** if it contains any special characters (space, backslash etc.) and that the URL is **case sensitive**.

You can copy the full URL from the `Web Services` page in the Business Central client.

Comment: as i've said, i dont have any problems with the web service, it is correctly setup. My problem is that i can't access the data from the webservice, because something is wrong fetching the table data. See updated question.

Comment: @JógvanReinertSamuelsen I have updated my answer according to your updated question.

Comment: urlencoding the body just messes it up even more :/

Comment: I have updated my answer once again.

Comment: and we're back on square 1, this really seems like an unsolvable problem :/
Yet again, i get an [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]

Comment: Could you update your question with the code you currently have after the various suggested modifications?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to fetch data from NAV 2018 webservice (page type api).
The error doesn't say anything so at the beginning please check what is inside. You can do it as following:

```js
console.error(JSON.stringify(err.request?.response))
```

or

```js
console.error(JSON.strigify(err.request))
```

After that we can go further.

In my scenario the issue was related to missing server certificate.